# Modifying a matrix entry based on the file loaded

Tags: matlab, file, matrix, switch-statement

I have a 30 files like this:

```
1-1.jpg, 1-2.jpg, ..., 1-10.jpg
2-1.png, 2-2.png, ..., 2-10.png
3-1.gif, 3-2.gif, ..., 3-10.gif
```

Now I want to use a switch case in this way:

- When I load `1-1.jpg` to `1-10.jpg` I get 1 for last column of my matrix
- When I load `2-1.png` to `2-10.png` I get 2 for last column of my matrix
- When I load `3-1.gif` to `3-10.gif` I get 3 for last column of my matrix

How can I do this? I don't want to use for loops because it will slow down the code significantly. For just one file I did this:

```
switch Filename
  case {'1.jpg'}
    Matrix(end) = 1;
  case {'2.png'}
    Matrix(end) = 2;
  case {'3.gif'}
    Matrix(end) = 3;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a for loop or a switch statement. You can just do this every time you load and process a file (using [`strtok`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtok.html) and [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html)):

```
intString = strtok(Filename, '.-');   % Get leading integers of file name string
Matrix(end) = str2double(intString);  % Convert string to integer and store in matrix
```

If you don't want to use the leading integers as the identifying label to put in `Matrix`, but instead want to use the file extension, you can do it using the functions [`fileparts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileparts.html) and [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) like so:

```
extList = {'.jpg'; '.png'; '.gif'};   % Create a list of valid extensions
[~, ~, ext] = fileparts(Filename);    % Get the file extension
[~, index] = ismember(ext, extList);  % Find its index in the list
Matrix(end) = index;
```

And the identifying label for each file type will be its position in `extList`.

Comment: How can i put this in if statement? for example if the strtok gets .jpg, puts 1 in last column of Matrix and if it gets .png in strtok puts 2 in last column and so on?

Comment: @lighting: Is the number you need the first character in the file name? If so, the above gets it for you and puts that in `Matrix` without the need for any if statement.

Comment: Well, actually i don't need the first character in the file name. i have 8 type of images and i want to put 1 to 8 label for them.(in last column of my matrix)

Comment: @lighting: I added another option to my answer that should do what you need.